# Hypothetical: "War as Text" lawsuit in Cryptonomicon

Tags: united-states, law-in-fiction

In Neil Stephenson's book "[Cryptonomicon](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Lw-00wTgBy8C&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=cryptonomicon%20war%20as%20text%20filing%20suit&source=bl&ots=Cz2ZPMF3-a&sig=ACfU3U3IVaaOASgdQJPX_VxBqZ1ZAHmfZg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNp4_P7J_pAhUBonEKHTOPDuoQ6AEwAHoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=cryptonomicon%20war%20as%20text%20filing%20suit&f=false)" there is an account of legal battles over a poster that was designed for an academic conference on "War as Text":

> [The artist] started with a black and white half-tone photo of a haggard World War Two [soldier]. He worked this image over with a photocopier, blowing the half-tone dots up into rough lumps like rubber balls chewed by a dog and wreaking any number of other distortions on it [...]. Then he added a few elements in colour; red lipstick, blue eye shadow, and a trace of a red brassiere strap peeking out from the soldier's unbuttoned uniform shirt.

The book goes on to describe how the soldier is subsequently tracked down.

> The artist who made the poster then confessed that he had simply copied it from a book. [...]. High-powered trial lawyers converged on the small town in Kentucky [where the soldier now lives]. [...] The veteran announced that he was filing civil suit against the [conference organisers]. The organising committee pulled the poster from circulation, which caused thousands of bootleg copies to go up on the World Wide Web [...]. They also filed suit against the artist, whose net worth was about a thousand dollars and debts (mostly college loans) amounting to sixty-five thousand.

I know this is all fiction, but do any of the parties in this have any actual grounds for a lawsuit? The book publisher and original photographer do not figure in the story, but the poster seems to have been both transformative and fair use. The soldier's case is not explained. Does he have some kind of libel or invasion of privacy case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does he have some kind of libel or invasion of privacy case?

The description of the "art work" is somewhat inconclusive. I will assume that the red lipstick and blue eye shadow in the fictional poster are suggestive of that soldier's "makeup".

If the World War Two soldier were still alive and a straight male, he might have a claim of defamation insofar as the poster portrayed him as having a sexual orientation which is inaccurate, detrimental to his reputation, and tending to dissuade others from associating with the soldier. Policies against sexual discrimination aside, no straight male likes being falsely characterized as to sexual orientation (in part because of the undeniably harmful, lasting impact something like this would have in his environment).

The defendant's possible allegation that the "art work" was hyperbole would be unavailing. That is because the suggestive poster is likely to impinge on viewers a detrimental concept of the soldier even if it is obvious to those viewers that the poster was not an actual, color photograph taken of him during the World War II.

In most jurisdictions in the US, the defamed soldier would need to file suit within a year from the publication of the poster (an exception is Tennessee: six months) because the statute of limitations for claims of defamation is shorter than most others.

Comment: There's no way that could be defamation in the US. No reasonable person could come to the conclusion that the artist has some knowledge about his sexual orientation. The picture is distorted and many decades old; it took effort to even find out who it was. And what's "his environment" - a nursing home? The ex-soldier would have to have been over 80 when the book was published. It's not like he's still a soldier. "A detrimental concept" is also not enough for defamation; you need some actual false facts.

Comment: @DM The book is set in about the year 2000. The ex-soldier is in good health and busy rebuilding Afro-American churches that have been burned down by "drunken yahoos".

Comment: @DM (1) A conclusion that the artist did not know the soldier's sexual orientation would establish *reckless disregard*, and hence *actual malice*. (2) The defamer's efforts as to soldier's identity further reinforces *reckless disregard* for defaming a person he knew exists/ed. (3) A WWII veteran, just like any civilian, retains his right to his good name & reputation even if his age is over 80, is no longer a soldier, and lives in a nursing home. (4) The defamatory falsehood would be artist's unfounded suggestion that the straight male was fond of cross-dressing and/or had akin inclinations.

Comment: @IñakiViggers I agree on (3). I'd agree on (1) if I though there was any actual fact to which malice could be ascribed. But I still disagree on (4). I mean, you yourself can't decide whether it's suggesting he was a transvestite or a homosexual. It's too vague to be actionable.

Comment: @DM (1) It is *reckless disregard* (and thus actual malice) to make a representation without having a bare clue of whether it is accurate. The defamer's cluelessness implies he entertained *serious doubts* as to the accuracy thereof. (4) A distinction between transvestite, homosexual, bisexual, transgender, etc. is irrelevant because they as falsehoods are equally injurious to the reputation of a straight male. No *straight* male would say "*The artist falsely portrayed me as a trans and not as a homosexual, so that's cool*".